# Can we migrate from Kafka(1.4.0) to RAFT(1.4.3) if channel capabilities are disabled?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, raft

While migrating from `kafka(Fabric 1.4.0)` to `RAFT(fabric 1.4.3)`, in first step I am changing the state of network form `NORMAL to MAINTENANCE`, after signing the block, when I send to the orderer, getting the following error.

> Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- config update for
>   existing channel did not pass maintenance checks: config transaction
>   inspection failed: next config attempted to change ConsensusType.State
>   to STATE_MAINTENANCE, but the capability is disabled

Can we enable channel capabilities for the network with version (1.4.0)?

Answer (score 0):

As the [latest](https://readthedocs.org/projects/hyperledger-fabric/downloads/pdf/latest/) HLF documentation suggests that Capabilities Requirements need to be set for Channel and Application, these need to be set to the current HLF version which is being migrated. For e.g., if the current Fabric version is 1.4.2, the requirement parameters need to be set as `V1_4_2: true`. See this [link](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_42750537/article/details/97763289) for additional clarification.